# Is it a good idea to use Pull Requests to notify branches to merge latest master?

Tags: git, pull-request

Master branch has been updated with latest production branch. In order to make sure all branches update with latest master branch changes.

Is it a good idea to use pull requests to request all branches to merge master?

If it's not, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make pull requests to signal changes to the upstream branch; however, you should consider the following:

- Pull request signal that you want something to be merge into the branch. You should either make them fully functional merges with the branches or mark them "work in process".
- Making pull request for every branch can put a lot of strain on the maintainer of the production branch; creating a new pull request for every branch on every change can be a lot of work.

You might want to consider alternatives instead. If it's just about notifying the project's contributors, you could start an e-mailing list or have them "watch" the main repository on your prefered git portal. Any kind of contact medium used for the project will do.

To ensure usage of the production code and avoid merge conflicts for the maintainers you can use a merge policy. In this case: only allow fast-forward merges back to the production branch. This will push the contributors to merge or rebase their code, before they create a pull request back to the production branch. You can usually restrict merge strategies in the repository settings of your prefered git portal.